# When should I need --clock parameter on rosbag play?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find any doc about parameter of rosbag play.

In rosbag video told that parameter.

How to use --clock parameter?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12577/when-should-i-need---clock-parameter-on-rosbag-play?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you run "`rosbag play --clock ...`" before your other nodes, it will set `use_sim_time` for you. If you prefer to launch the other nodes first, be sure to set it yourself, as @michikarg recommends.

In addition, the `--clock` option causes `rosbag play` to publish simulated time synchronized to the messages in the bag file to the [`/clock` topic](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock). That way, your other nodes run as if they were executing when those messages were originally published.

**CORRECTION**: My mistake, `rosbag play` does *not* set `use_sim_time` for you. Setting it yourself is a good idea. That typically needs to be done before the other nodes start up.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-13**:
Probably, you either forgot to set `use_sim_time` first, or you did not specify `--clock` on the playback.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-01-13**:
Does 'they were executing when those messages were originally published' means it use the original timestamp when I recording? But when I rosbag play, receiver always get the latest timestamp and always different. What happened?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2019-01-03**:
Basically, without `--clock`, nothing gets published on `/clock`. And if `use_sim_time` is `true`, it needs stuff on `/clock`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think what you are searching for is the /time topic that has to be published when running in simulation or playing rosbags. In your case this should be done automatically by rosbag but you have to tell your master that you use simulation time. You can do so by:

rosparam set use_sim_time true

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-01-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-01-11**:
After I use 'rosparam set use_sim_time true', I can't figure out the difference of adding --clock parameter. When should I use --clock? Thank you~

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-03-31**:
When you want rosbag to publish the original times of the messages.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-03-31**:
When is the case of using 'rosparam set use_sim_time true'? I can't find /time topic when I run 'rosparam set use_sim_time true & rosbag play ...'.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-01**:
The /time topic has been replaced by the /clock topic.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-04-01**:
Thank you. Now I know --clock is for publish /clock topic, but I still unknown that when is the case of using 'rosparam set use_sim_time true'? I have tested it and I found it is different with --clock, but I can figure out what's its usage.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this works for me.

Start ROS, but not your nodes.

Start using simulated time:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

Start your nodes.

Start playback:

```
rosbag play --clock <bag_file>
```

---

Originally posted by [gbohus](https://answers.ros.org/users/58051/gbohus/) with karma: 63 on 2021-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3